# SQLite3 count how many counts?

Tags: database, sqlite, count

I'm learning SQLite3 and having trouble with this particular output.
Let's say I have a column like:

```
user0
user1
user1
user2
user2
user3
user3
user3
user4
user4
user4
user4
```

I would like to count how many times a user appears in the column, and having an output like:

```
1 | 1
2 | 2
1 | 3
1 | 4
```

Meaning: There is 1 user appearing 1 time, 2 users appearing 2 times, 1 user appearing 3 times, 1 user appearing 4 times.

I don't need to know anything else, only how many users are with how many accounts.

Comment: I think a "group by" might help you

Comment: `GROUP BY` and `count()`, yes. Read up on grouping and aggregate functions in your favorite SQL guide.

Answer (score 1):

You `group by` once to get the counters of the 1st column you need and then again on this result:

```
select count(*) total, counter
from (
  select count(*) counter 
  from tablename
  group by col
)
group by counter
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3fiwjNP6s4cBPk2vKEH5Lj/0)
Results:

```
| total | counter |
| ----- | ------- |
| 1     | 1       |
| 2     | 2       |
| 1     | 3       |
| 1     | 4       |
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, only changed the order of [count(*) total, counter] to [counter, count)*) total] to have the exact same output of my example, in case anyone needs this :)

Comment: This is the order of your expected result. You can check the demo.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example using GROUP BY and the COUNT()-function.
Im using MSSQL, but it should be nearly the same in SQLITE3.
This is the table Im using:

[image]

```
select count([name]), [name] from Test
group by [name]
```

This is the result:

[image]